# Water consumption of the average housefly

Tags: entomology, scatology

So, I have this question:

How much water does the common fly consume in its lifetime?

I was able to find the following facts:

1. Born from swine waste under 40% (waste to water ratio)
2. Lifespan of 15-25 days
3. They are 40-45% water (the flies)
4. avereage weight (in mg) 0.005 to 0.01 (the flies)

Also, I'm not sure where, but, I heard that flies defecate whenever they land, but I'm not sure on size or frequency.

Here are my resources:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Housefly

https://www.arrowexterminators.com/learning-center/pest-library/flies/house-flies

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Average-weight-of-flies-Each-bar-represents-the-mean-and-range-thstandard-deviation-The_fig3_318433682

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this stack and what makes a good question and answer. That being said, we need a bit more information in your post (edit these into the question) - What are your units for the values 0.005 and 0.01 in the list. What is under 40% in point 1. Were you able to find anything on how frequently they drank?

Comment: Please don’t waste space telling us you have a question. We’re smart enough to work that out as this is a question and answer site. More to the point, explain why you wish to know something that most of us would find completely uninteresting, and why you think modern biologists would clog their minds with such things. Houseflies, bedbugs, moths, dung beetles… What next?